# ExpandableListView using Volley

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am new to expandable listview. I am getting all categories in two level using expandable listview. but that is not being done by me .  I am using expandable listview in fragment. How i can show categories of two level using expanable listview.
here is my fragment code:

```
private Context context;
private  ExpandableListView expandableListView;
private  ExpandableCategoryAdapter adapter;
private  HashMap<String, List<Category>> hashMap;
private  ArrayList<Category> header =  new ArrayList<>();
 int id ;
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context = context;
}
public void getInfo(View view){
    expandableListView = view.findViewById(R.id.expandableLvCategory);

   }
  public void setInfo(){

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args  != null){
        id = args.getInt("Id");
        Log.e("ID",String.valueOf(id));
    }
    getAllCategories();
    adapter = new ExpandableCategoryAdapter(context, header, hashMap);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new 
  ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, long id) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new 
  ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    header.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new 
   ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    header.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    // Listview on child click listener
    expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new 
 ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, 
long id) {

            Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    header.get(groupPosition)
                            + " : "
                            + hashMap.get(
                            header.get(groupPosition)).get(
                            childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return false;
        }
    });
   }

private void setTitleCategory(JSONObject object) {
header = new ArrayList<Category>();
 List<Category> child1 = new ArrayList<Category>();
    List<Category> child2 = new ArrayList<Category>();
    hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < object.length(); i++) {
        {
            try {
                JSONObject object1 = object.getJSONObject("ListCategories");
                final String name1 = object1.getString("CategoryName");
                header.add(new Category(1,name1 + i));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    // Adding child data
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        child1.add(new Category(1,"Hello" + i));
    }
 //        // Adding child data
//        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
//            child2.add("Child" + i);
//        }

    // Adding header and childs to hash map
    ///  hashMap.put(header.get(0), child1);
 //        hashMap.put(header.get(1), child2);


}

private void getAllCategories() {

    StringRequest request =new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,  
URLs.viewAllCategory
            , new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject object =new JSONObject(response);
               // JSONArray headerArray = 
 object.getJSONArray("ListCategories");

                setTitleCategory(object);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.e("Expandablecaetgory",response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("id",String.valueOf(id));
            return params;
        }
    };
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(request);
}

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,   
  @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = 
  inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_level_two_main_menu,container,false);
    getInfo(view);

    setInfo();
    return view;
 }
```

and here is my adapter code. How I can implement it

```
private Context _context;
private ArrayList<Category> header; // header titles
// Child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<Category>> child;
final String name = null;
private TextView header_text;

public ExpandableCategoryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Category> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<Category>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this.header = listDataHeader;
    this.child = listChildData;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // Get header size
    return header.size();

}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // return children count
    return this.child.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // Get header position
    return this.header.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // This will return the child
    return child.get(header.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Getting header title
   // String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

    // Inflating header layout and setting text
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group_category, parent, false);
    }
     header_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
     setData(header.get(groupPosition));

    if (isExpanded) {
        header_text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        header_text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.up, 0);
    } else {

        header_text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        header_text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.down, 0);
    }

    return convertView;
}

private void setData(final Category category) {
    header_text.setText(category.getCategoryName());
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Getting child text
    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_category, parent, false);
    }

    //set content in the child views
    TextView child_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);

    child_text.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Volley is a networking library. It probably shouldn't have anything to do with how you display data downloaded via Volley.

Comment: how i can make expandable listview by fetching data from URL